# I'm using MATLAB R2015b, How do we generate a rectangular matrix with upper diagonal elements 1?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to generate a rectangular matrix with 1s on the diagonal above the main diagonal and -1s on the main diagonal.  I used "eye" which does not create the diagonal above the main. 
Please find my attempt to this below.

```
N = 5
M1 =  -eye([N-1 N]) 
M2 =  eye([N N-1])'
M = M1+M2
```

I am unable to resolve this issue on my own. Any help or links to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any prebuild function, but you can easily make such a matrix yourself:

```
N=5;
M=7;
diag=-eye(N,M);
upper_diag=horzcat(zeros(N,1),eye(N,M-1))
final=diag+upper_diag
```

using the identity matrix and some concatenation to shift the diagonal around. This example assumes you are looking for a square matrix.

The result looks like:

final =

```
-1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0    -1     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0    -1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0    -1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0    -1     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is good for a square matrix, which could be done easier with 
M1 =  diag(-ones(N,1)) + diag(ones(N-1,1),1). I was looking for a rectangular matrix.

Comment: @Suga You are right. I did not read your question properly. Sorry. I have edited my answer for a rectangular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Just create `eye` and `diag` matrices as per normal, add them together, then chop away the rows you do not need:

```
nCol = 7;
nRow = 5;
M = -eye(nCol) + diag(ones(nCol - 1, 1), 1);
M = M(1:nRow, 1:nCol)
```

produces

```
M =

    -1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0    -1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0    -1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0    -1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0    -1     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

The four-input version of [`spdiags`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) does just that, producing a sparse matrix. You may need to convert to [`full`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) then.

```
M = 5; %// number of rows
N = 7; %// number of columns
d = [0 1]; %// specify main diagonal and the one above
v = [-1 1]; %// values in those diagonals
result = full(spdiags(ones(M,1)*v, d, M, N));
```

This gives

```
result =
    -1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0    -1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0    -1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0    -1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0    -1     1     0
```